# Function for calling a function repeatedly?

Tags: python, iterator, iteration

Consider the hypothetical function `repeatcall`, that takes as arguments a no-args callable `func` and a positive integer `n`, and returns a list whose members are obtained by executing `func()` `n` times.  It supports an infinite stream of silly hijinks like:

```
>>> repeatcall(lambda: id(dict()), 5)
[45789920, 45788064, 45807216, 45634816, 45798640]

>>> urandom = lambda: struct.unpack('Q', open('/dev/urandom').read(8))[0]
>>> repeatcall(urandom, 3)
[3199039843823449742, 14990726001693341311L, 11583468019313082272L]

>>> class Counter(itertools.count): __call__ = itertools.count.next
>>> repeatcall(Counter(100, -2), 4)
[100, 98, 96, 94]
```

I could swear that I've seen a function like `repeatcall` somewhere in the Python 2.x standard libraries, but I can't find it.  If I didn't dream this, where **in the standard library** can I find it?

**PS: I know it's trivial to roll one's own, but I hate to reinvent wheels, especially those are already in the standard library.  I am *not* asking how to roll my own.**

Edit: made it *even more explicit* that I am not asking how to code `repeatcall`.

Comment: isn't it just mapping across a range?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've seen this in the standard library docs, not the standard library itself.

It's `repeatfunc` from the [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def repeatfunc(func, times=None, *args):
    """Repeat calls to func with specified arguments.

    Example:  repeatfunc(random.random)
    """
    if times is None:
        return starmap(func, repeat(args))
    return starmap(func, repeat(args, times))
```

It allows arguments and should (theoretically) perform better than a list comprehension because `func` only has to be looked up once. `repeat` is also faster than `range` for when you're not actually using the counter.

Comment: Technically yours isn't the exact answer either, unless you are saying that it does not exist in the stdlib. I don't think a recipe making use of `itertools.starmap` is any different than rolling your own. Though I suppose by showing this, you are in a round about way saying you have to roll your own.

Comment: @jdi Yes, I'm staying it doesn't exist in the standard library. He remembers seeing it because it's in the docs. That is the answer to his question.

Comment: Then I suppose 90% of what you wrote isn't necessary if he isn't interested in seeing any implementations of the code. So really, that 90% is just like the others.

Comment: @jdi That 90% is included simply so people don't have to click through to the `itertools` docs to see what I'm talking about. SO answers are supposed to stand on their own as much as possible, not depend on external resources.

Comment: Ok then lets just say 30% isn't needed, since the explanation at the end was just frosting :-)

Comment: @jdi Yes, that's really a comment on my own answer rather than part of the answer itself :)

Comment: I guess the return should be wrapped in `list()` to actually return a list with the results right ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D If you actually want a list with all of the results, sure -- one of the big advantages of itertools is you can get just one thing at a time if you don't need them all at once.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Yes, if you're calling the function a **finite** number of times, and you're OK with waiting until the _last_ instance of the function to finish before seeing the _first_. But if you want to iterate back over the function outputs as they occur (for example, if using [epoll](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html): `for fn, ev in ( event for events in repeatfunc(E.poll) for event in events ):`), then the liberty to consume the generator only as-needed can be a godsend.

Answer (score 4):

There's a reason this doesn't exist: the idiomatic way to code a function that doesn't take arguments on each invocation, and returns something new is to code it as a generator.

You would then use a list comprehension or generator expression to call it as many times as you like: `[next(gen) for i in xrange(5)]`. Better yet, `gen` can itself be the result of a generator expression like `(id(dict()) for i in (itertools.repeat(None)))`.

Thus, **python has no library support for this because it supports it syntactically.**

Comment: You're right, that is more "Pythonic" than the solution in the `itertools` recipes. But, like all the others, this isn't an answer to the question. He was asking where he'd seen an implementation, not how to do it. This would have been a good comment.

Comment: @agf Not really. This requires at leas two paragraphs, and it does explain why there is no solution of the form that OP asks for.

Comment: His question isn't "is this in the standard library", it's "I've seen this before; I think it was in the standard library but I can't find it. Where is it?" A comment fits 500 characters; your post has room to spare, and no formatted blocks that you couldn't display in a comment.

Comment: @agf If you feel that strongly, flag it. Why are you so angry at everyone else who has posted an answer?

Comment: There's no "anger" in it. When an answer doesn't address the question, it's noise. When I've made a mistake and posted something not on-point, I delete it, and I appreciate it when others point out my mistakes. Unless an answer contains _no information_ I don't flag it; the decision to remove it or not is the poster's, see [my meta question on the subject](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108143/moderator-deletion-of-equivalent-answers). And I don't downvote because the intention was to provide useful information, and the information isn't wrong.

Comment: Clearly, you have some anger though, since you just downvoted my (correct) answer. I just saw [this answer and comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10172286/how-come-i-cant-get-the-exactly-result-to-pip-install-by-manually-python-set/10172319#comment13058111_10172319) -- I'm surprised you'd downvote an answer that was correct after a disagreement, since that comment makes it pretty clear you think that's wrong.

Comment: @agf I downvoted your answer because you have complained about every single other answer on flimsy grounds. That's not cool.

Comment: What about for a for loop, though? I'm looking for the same answer, and while generator or list comprehensions are good, `for n in (func() for i in range(10))` seems a bit awkward

Comment: @Lucretiel I'm not sure what you mean. There is no reason for you to have a for loop and generator expression in your example. Just write: `for i in range(10): func()`, or if you want to have an iterable to pass elsewhere, use `(func() for i in range(10))`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
>> from random import random
>> print [random() for x in range(5)]
[0.015015074309405185,
 0.7877023608913573,
 0.2940706206824023,
 0.7140457069245207,
 0.07868376815555878]
```

Seems succinct enough no?

Comment: "I know it's trivial to roll one's own, but I hate to reinvent wheels" -- this doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [apply](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#apply) built-in function for this purpose

```
>>> def repeatcall(func,n):
    [apply(func) for i in range(0,n)]

>>> repeatcall(lambda: id(dict()), 5)
[56422096, 56422240, 56447024, 56447168, 56447312]

>>> import itertools
>>> class Counter(itertools.count): __call__ = itertools.count.next

>>> repeatcall(Counter(100, -2), 4)
[100, 98, 96, 94]
>>>
```

Note**
From the manual
The use of apply() is equivalent to function(*args, **keywords).

So repeatcall can also be written as

```
>>> def repeatcall(func,n):
    [func() for i in range(0,n)]
```

Comment: `apply` has been deprecated since python2.3. You can just call the function with its *args and **kwargs

Comment: the function can be called directly, even if it's name is passed in as an argument:  def repeatcall(func,n): return [func() for i in range(0,n)]

Comment: yes apply is completely unnecessary here and everywhere else.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question -- "I know it's trivial to roll one's own, but I hate to reinvent wheels". He didn't want an implementation.

Comment: @agf: The postscript was added 15 mins after the original question :-)

Comment: No, it wasn't. Look at the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10048916/revisions); it's in the original version, just not bold.

Answer (score 1):

While reading comments here I realized that `iter(foo, expr)` will create an infinite iterator of the result of `foo` as long as it never equals `expr`.

for the example in the question, `iter(lambda: id(dict()), None)` will create an infinite iterator of ids of dicts.

While not a direct answer to this question, I found it useful since in my usecase I wanted it to be part of a finite `zip` expression anyways and just needed the iterator to keep producing elements.

hopefully this might help others that stumble upon this question