# How come I can't get the exactly result to *pip install* by manually *python setup.py install*?

Tags: python, setuptools

I like to figure out the myth behind Python's namespace packages by *setuptools*, and here is what I did test.

- Make a *virtual environment* by `virtualenv`.
- Find a namespaced package on *PyPI*.
- Install that package by `pip install`.
- Check the installed file hierarchy.

The package I played with is [zope.interface](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.interface) and it worked well with the following file hierarchy on my virtualenv:

```
~virenv/.../site-packages/zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.6-nspkg.pth
                         /zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.6.egg-info/
                         /zope/
                              /interface/
                                        /...
```

Everything looked fine and I love the way *zope.interface* got installed as a real namespaced package (under folder *zope*).

Then, I did another test and that's the question I would like to ask for your help. I downloaded the tared *zope.interface* source file. I liked to play it manually again

- Make a *virtual environment* by `virtualenv`.
- Untar the *zope.interface* into somewhere.
- Install the package by `python setup.py install`.
- Go check what happened in *site-packages*.

The *site-packages* looks like this:

```
~virenv/../site-packages/zope.interface-...egg/
                                              /zope/
                                                   /__init__.py
                                                   /interface/
                                              /EGG-INFO/
```

Q. How come I can't get the exactly result to `pip install` by manually `python setup.py install`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`pip` uses `setup.py` internally. It just passes additional option to it. To reproduce what `pip` is doing, execute

```
python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed
```

You can also run `pip -vv` to see exactly which commands are run.

Comment: In order to make this work, it seems I need to provide *--root* or *--record* then~ It looks to me that I have to prepare something like *~zope.interface-3.8.0-py2.6.egg-info/installed-files.txt* for *--record*. Am I right?

Comment: exact command it runs: `python -c "import setuptools; __file__='/path/to/setup.py'; execfile('/path/to/setup.py')" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-NM9sBK-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /site-packages/path`

Answer (score -8):

> Q. How come I can't get the exactly result to pip install by manually
>   python setup.py install?

Because `pip` and `setup.py` are two different pieces of software.

`pip` is not advertised as providing identical behaviour to `setup.py`, nor vice versa.

If you want the behaviour of `pip`, use `pip`; if you want the behaviour of `setup.py`, use `setup.py`.

Comment: Wow! Really? Never thought about this!

Comment: still looking for possible description or even solution to this cause I do need that clean file hierarchy by *pip* but with *setup.py* way.

Comment: @DrakeGuan: You should change the title of your question to reflect your last comment. What's the difference between pip and setup.py isn't much of a question, it seems like you're actually interested in something a bit more specific.

Comment: @DrakeGuan If you want the behaviour of `pip`, use `pip`.

Comment: That's somewhat misleading, though - `pip` does use `setup.py`. I'm sure if you get the right options, or possibly use a wrapper script, it's possible to get the same results with setup.py.

Comment: This is incorrect. In most cases, pip does download the package from PyPI, unzip it and run the setup.py script (albeit with some extra options). If you try to have pip install from a tarball for example without a setup.py, you'll get an error saying so.

Comment: @ThomasK Sure, but that's not the question - the question is why the one does not give identical results to the other.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim In what way is this incorrect? Just because pip expects a setup.py it does not mean that pip does not provide any other behaviour.

Comment: dude, you answer is just plain wrong. And downvoting my answer won't change that.

Comment: @vartec How is my answer wrong? The reason OP does not get exactly the same behaviour from setup.py as from pip is because they are not the same programme, nor are they supposed to be. Whether or not he could use some combination of switches to achieve that is irrelevant.

Comment: @Marcin: Obviously they're not the same program: they have different names. But your answer fails to highlight the connection (one calls the other), or explain how to get `setup.py` to do what the OP wants. So it's technically correct, but not useful. @vartec has provided what the OP was almost certainly looking for.

Comment: @vartec Are you? I'm answering the question that was asked.

Comment: @ThomasK That still does not make my answer "misleading" as you so charmingly put it.

Comment: @Marcin: Implying that they're entirely separate when `pip` calls `setup.py` is misleading.

Comment: @ThomasK Not really. `pip` probably also uses `list`, but it doesn't follow that they are connected. The question does not ask "how can I re-implement `pip` myself".

Comment: @Marcin: In the context of installing a package, pip and setup.py are clearly connected.

Comment: @ThomasK They may be "connected" but the question doesn't ask "are they connected" - it asks why they don't have the exact same behaviour, and the answer is because they are not supposed to. That's all there is to it; how they achieve those effects is not relevant.

Comment: @Marcin: By strict literalism, yes, you have correctly answered the question. But the details are relevant: it's pretty clear that the OP wants some understanding of why they behave differently, or a way to modify the behaviour of one. It's like answering "why do I perceive red differently from blue" with "because they're different colours". Correct, but useless.

Comment: @ThomasK What other answer is there? There is no reason whatsoever to expect them to have the same behaviour. You might as well complain that I haven't dumped the whole code for pip in my answer.

Comment: @Marcin: Of course you can expect them to have similar behaviour: they both serve to install a Python package. It's different behaviour that needs explanation. As for another answer: @vartec's answer is a good start - providing a single option to `setup.py` makes it behave like `pip`. That's relevant and likely useful.

Comment: @ThomasK Why does different behaviour need explanation? `pip` does not advertise that it provides identical behaviour (nor vice versa). In so far as they are supposed to be similar, they are similar: they install a python package. To expect a different explanation is like asking why you and I don't use the same writing style: neither of us has indicated that we would.

Comment: @Marcin: Different behaviour requires explanation because the question is about the difference in behaviour. Where would humanity be if we never asked how or why?

Comment: @ThomasK Where would we be if we constantly asked trivial questions? Different things are different. If OP wants to know about the implementation, he is free to look at the source.

Comment: @Marcin: Almost all code questions could be answered by reading enough source, but asking can give more useful information more quickly. Re different things: see red/blue example above.

Comment: @ThomasK The reason why you don't perceive blue and red as exactly the same thing is because they are not exactly the same thing. There is no deeper explanation than that. If you want to inquire into the mechanisms of perception, that is a different question.

Comment: @Marcin: You're trolling, aren't you?

Comment: @ThomasK Certainly not. Are you trolling? You are the one who is defending a question that amounts to "why are two distinct things not the same?"

Comment: @Marcin: In both the OP's question and my red/blue example, saying "because they're different" does not convey any information that the asker did not already know. Assuming the question is posed in order to gain information, an answer that does not provide information has no value. A useful answer to the OP's question might discuss how the difference is implemented, or why developers chose different mechanisms. For the red/blue conundrum, a useful answer might cover wavelengths of light, pigments, and colour receptors in the eye.

Comment: @ThomasK In neither case does the mechanism answer the "why" question: it amounts to a restatement of the fact that the programme/eye works in a particular way. You are essentially complaining that I didn't make up a question that like more, and choose to answer that.

Comment: @Marcin: The details of the way that the programme/eye works can be informative and interesting. Given that the question is asked to gain information, if the literal answer to the question contains no information, we can infer that we have misunderstood what the asker wants. In that case, we can attempt to infer the question they meant to ask, and provide useful information. This process does not always work perfectly, but it's better than an answer with no information.

Comment: @ThomasK You may doubt your powers of comprehension, but I am confident in my own. When someone asks a nonsensical question, I assume they don't know that what they are asking is nonsensical, rather than inferring that it is an oblique way of soliciting a general disquisition on the topics mentioned. In that case, informing them that their question is nonsensical is new information.

Comment: @Marcin: No, the question can be clearly understood to have a rational answer, more specific than a general discussion. Possible readings are "how can I make them behave in the same way" (which vartec answered), "how do they achieve different results" (similar), or "why did the developers choose different mechanisms?" (we can presume the `pip` developers were aware of the other mechanism).

Comment: @ThomasK the very fact that you identify three possible topics shows that all that can be provided is general information of some kind. SO is not about making up your own better question and answering it.

Comment: @Marcin: SO is not about providing unhelpful overly-literal answers. To provide useful information, we often have to infer a 'better question'. The vote counts on these answers suggest other users think that providing some useful information is better than a literal but unhelpful answer.

Comment: @ThomasK Leave the votes of others out of it - you are still arguing that I should make up a new question. If you want this to be a different question, go ahead and edit it.

Comment: @Marcin: The votes of others became relevant when the discussion moved to what SO is about. In as much as SO is a community, what it is about is determined by the opinions of its members.

Comment: @ThomasK Well, if you really want to argue about that, it turns out that SO users don't have to leave a reasoned explanation for their downvotes. For example, I am getting a bunch of downvotes on old questions, which I assume come from you (for obvious reasons) and vartec (whenever he sees my handle he is reminded that I once pointed out an error in one of his answers). So no, they don't really convey much information.

Comment: @Marcin: I have not gone back to downvote your other answers, and I do not intend to.

Comment: @ThomasK Perhaps vartec is feeling extra insecure today.

Comment: @Marcin: *bzzzt*, that's an ad hominem. Thanks for playing.

Comment: @ThomasK No, it's not an *ad hominem*. Look it up. OTOH, your comment *is* a childish attempt to provide an excuse to withdraw from the discussion.

Comment: I **will** downvote any answer that is clearly wrong. @Marcin: if you can name any of your **correct** answers that I've allegedly downvoted, don't be shy, mention it.

Comment: @vartec You know that I can't tell who is downvoting my answers, especially as you never leave comments. One presumes that is because you have no valid criticisms.

Comment: @ThomasK: he means his great answers like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129080/analysis-and-design-for-functional-programming/10129172#10129172

Comment: @vartec I note that you haven't left a comment on that. I defy you to locate any inaccuracies in that answer.

Comment: I'm not going to try to arbitrate on other answers. Withdrawing from the discussion, on the other hand, sounds like an excellent idea. @Marcin, good luck trying to argue the case for this answer.

Comment: @Marcin: I don't have to. There are plenty of comments already. FYI I've also flagged that for moderator attention as *"not an answer"*. You keep using SO answers to boost your ego w/o any benefit to the community. You **will** get downvoted.

Comment: @ThomasK There's no case to be argued. You have spent several hours complaining that I have provided an answer to the question asked, not to your preferred question. You could complain about every other question on SO on that basis.

Comment: @Marcin: any FYI, your revenge downvotes **will** get revoked.

Comment: @vartec Just because you string some words together, it doesn't follow that they make sense. You're the one whose fragile ego has lead you to engage in a campaign of downvoting my answers willy-nilly.

Comment: @vartec Unlikely. It's good to know that you don't understand the downvote-reversing system.

Comment: I really appreciate your work and comments on this thread. Actually those comments run beyond my expectation. I might need to re-check my question statements for clarity, or I should fire another question then~